# How to determine if a function parameter is annotated?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm annotating function parameters as shown below with the label `bar`.

```
int foo (char* s __attribute__((annotate("bar")))) {
  ...
}
```

Next, I am running a function pass. How can I determine if a given function argument is annotated with the label `bar`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read the [llvm.var.annotation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-var-annotation-intrinsic) and [llvm.dbg.declare](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html#llvm-dbg-declare) intrinsics.

More specifically, here is the llvm-ir generated by your code above:

```
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"bar\00", section "llvm.metadata"
@.str.1 = private unnamed_addr constant [75 x i8] c"/tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler117030-12962-1rhu4lb.ojfaiz4cxr/example.cpp\00", section "llvm.metadata"

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @foo(char*)(i8*) #0 !dbg !6 {
  %2 = alloca i8*, align 8
  store i8* %0, i8** %2, align 8
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i8** %2, metadata !12, metadata !13), !dbg !14
  %3 = bitcast i8** %2 to i8*
  call void @llvm.var.annotation(i8* %3, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([75 x i8], [75 x i8]* @.str.1, i32 0, i32 0), i32 1)
  ret i32 0, !dbg !15
}

!6 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "foo", linkageName: "foo(char*)", scope: !1, file: !1, line: 1, type: !7, isLocal: false, isDefinition: true, scopeLine: 1, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, isOptimized: false, unit: !0, variables: !2)
!7 = !DISubroutineType(types: !8)
!8 = !{!9, !10}
!9 = !DIBasicType(name: "int", size: 32, align: 32, encoding: DW_ATE_signed)
!10 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_pointer_type, baseType: !11, size: 64, align: 64)
!11 = !DIBasicType(name: "char", size: 8, align: 8, encoding: DW_ATE_signed_char)
!12 = !DILocalVariable(name: "s", arg: 1, scope: !6, file: !1, line: 1, type: !10)
```

The dbg.declare instruction tells you that %2 is actually the first parameter of the function (named s).

%3 is a bitcast of %2, so basically an alias.

And the the llvm.var.annotation instruction tells you that %2 is annotated with the constant string @str, which value is "bar".